# How to efficiently make the Grid take space based on the content inside of it?

Tags: html, css

That's a prime example of something that CSS Grid will do better than flexbox. Something like this:

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 72%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 24px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  max-width:110px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 Here the cards looks good as the number of cards are more
<div id ="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<hr/>
we have so much white space between cards, how can we get rid of the space as the cards can be dynamic like 2 or 1. and a max of 3 per container
<div id ="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can we have the space between grids and make them left aligned so that it , fits correctly as the top cards, dynamically adjust using Css Grids or is there any efficient way of achieving this.

Note - One thing that blocks me here is we cannot have a fixed width and then have the grid at 3 columns as we donot want to have empty spaces when the container is resized

Comment: did you try `auto-fill` instead of `auto-fit` ?

Comment: Yes i did, but then when resizing it doesn't fit and leaves a empty area on the right side of the container

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `minmax(100px, 1fr)` and just use a fixed column width. Here is an example:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 100px);
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 72%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 24px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  max-width: 110px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Here the cards looks good as the number of cards are more
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<hr/> we have so much white space between cards, how can we get rid of the space as the cards can be dynamic like 2 or 1. and a max of 3 per container
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: aligning it center will not solve the purpose here i feel more like a left aligned view will be more user would prefer

Comment: I did not change the alignment, just the grid column sizes. But I can edit my snippet if you want

Comment: also in case of 3 cards when we shrink we donot want empty space on the side of the div so that also we need to consider here

Comment: I am not sure I understand

Comment: while resizing the container if you observe the inside cards takes the full width and dosent leave any space which makes it look good . that is also one part of the puzzle i donot want to break

Comment: Sorry, you have lost me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 15px;
}

.three-col-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 72%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 24px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.l-wrap {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.grid-item {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.grid-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
Here the cards looks good as the number of cards are more
<div class="l-wrap">
  <div class="three-col-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-inner">Grid item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-inner">Grid item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-inner">Grid item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-inner">Grid item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-inner">Grid item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>we have so much white space between cards, how can we get rid of the space as the cards can be dynamic like 2 or 1. and a max of 3 per container
<div class="l-wrap">
  <div class="three-col-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-inner">Grid item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-inner">Grid item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```